# How to build boost iostreams with gzip and bzip2 support on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, bzip2, boost-iostreams

How do I build `boost`'s `iostreams` library with `gzip` and `bzip2` support?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I am no expert, but this worked for me.

**Option 1 (straight from source)**

1. Download source files for [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) and for [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html).
2. Extract the downloads to directories, move directories to somewhere you like. I had to avoid `C:\Program Files (x86)\` as I couldn't get it to work with spaces in the directory name, so I created `C:\Sys\` and used that.
3. Open a command prompt with elevated privileges (run as administrator), go to your `boost` directory, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50_0\` and type `b2.exe --with-iostreams -s BZIP2_SOURCE=C:\Sys\bzip2-1.0.6 -s ZLIB_SOURCE=C:\Sys\zlib-1.2.7`
4. Verify that `C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_50_0\stage\lib` contains the wanted files, e.g. `libboost_zlib-vc100-*-1_50` and `libboost_bzip2-vc100-*-1_50`.

**Option 2 (build from source first)**

1. As above, download the source files.
2. Open a `Visual Studio Command Prompt` with elevated privileges (run as administrator)
3. Go to `C:\Sys\zlib-1.2.7>` and type `nmake -f win32\Makefile.msc`. This will build `zlib`.
4. Go to `C:\Sys\bzip2-1.0.6>` and type `nmake -f makefile.msc`. This will build `gzip2`.
5. The command for `boost` now becomes `b2.exe --with-iostreams -s BZIP2_BINARY=libbz2 -s BZIP2_INCLUDE=C:/Sys/bzip2-1.0.6 -s BZIP2_LIBPATH=C:/Sys/bzip2-1.0.6 -s ZLIB_BINARY=zlib -s ZLIB_INCLUDE=C:/Sys/zlib-1.2.7 -s ZLIB_LIBPATH=C:/Sys/zlib-1.2.7`

Comment: This stinks. If I provide invalid zlib path it still builds. Is there a person that used boost without spending several days struggling with it?

Comment: if this does not work for you, omit '-s' and instead set environment variable s ie. 'SET ZLIB_INCLUDE="path/to/file'  etc... then run b2 that worked for me

Comment: You might also need to adjust the toolset and address-model values to match the pre-compiled zlib and bzip2 binaries. See http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compilers

Comment: I was able to include from a path with a space by using dos 8.3 filename for Program Files:  b2.exe --with-iostreams -s ZLIB_SOURCE="C:\Progra~1\boost\zlib-1.2.11" -s NO_BZIP2=1

Comment: I had to use absolute paths for the source specifiers.  Relative paths did not work.

Comment: Why is there no way to use CFLAGS and LIBS (i.e., `ZLIB_CFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags zlib.pc)`)