# Boost iostreams with bzip - unresolved symbols

Tags: c++, boost, unresolved-external, bzip2, boost-iostreams

My project was using an older version of Boost's iostreams w/ bzip2. I'm now trying to upgrade to Boost 1.51. At first I did not compile with bzip so obviously I got the linker yelling about libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib being missing. I then followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282645/how-to-build-boost-iostreams-with-gzip-and-bzip2-support-on-windows) (and added the static flag) to compile this file.

However, running the linker now returns a bunch of symbols missing:

```
>error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_base::~bzip2_base(void)" (??1bzip2_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAE@XZ)
>error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_base::bzip2_base(struct boost::iostreams::bzip2_params const &)" (??0bzip2_base@detail@iostreams@boost@@IAE@ABUbzip2_params@23@@Z)
>error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const boost::iostreams::bzip2::stream_end" (?stream_end@bzip2@iostreams@boost@@3HB)
...
```

Any ideas how come the lib doesn't contain all this code? What am I missing?
I'm using VS2010 on Windows.

---

Edit: Got it!

Had an old version of libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib that was compiled without the bzip. What I'm still not sure about is this: For my original compilation I used:

```
>b2 --with-iostreams -sBZIP2_SOURCE=D:\Work\external\bzip2-1.0.6 -sZLIB_SOURCE=d:\work\external\zlib-1.2.3 runtime-link=static
```

This produced the following files:

```
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
```

For the "correct" compilation (that solved the problem) I used:

```
>b2 --with-iostreams -sBZIP2_SOURCE=D:\Work\external\bzip2-1.0.6 runtime-link=static
```

I.e. simply removed the zlib, as it was unnecessary for me. It produced:

```
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
```

How come the iostreams libs were not produced on the original compilation? Very odd.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with the solution, put it as a proper answer and accept it.

Comment: Tried to, but because I only registered a little while ago apparently I don't have enough reputation to answer my own questions...

Comment: @E.K. try to login to some more StackOverflow sites to get reputation boost.

Comment: @E.K. try self-answering now -- the limitation on self-answers by low-rep users is only an eight-hour delay (spam control), not a permanent restriction.

Comment: Be glad this fixed your errors - I have the `libboost_iostreams` lib file and I still get the errors...

Answer (score 1):

From E.K.'s answer-in-question:

Had an old version of libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib that was compiled without the bzip. What I'm still not sure about is this: For my original compilation I used:

```
>b2 --with-iostreams -sBZIP2_SOURCE=D:\Work\external\bzip2-1.0.6 -sZLIB_SOURCE=d:\work\external\zlib-1.2.3 runtime-link=static
```

This produced the following files:

```
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
```

For the "correct" compilation (that solved the problem) I used:

```
>b2 --with-iostreams -sBZIP2_SOURCE=D:\Work\external\bzip2-1.0.6 runtime-link=static
```

I.e. simply removed the zlib, as it was unnecessary for me. It produced:

```
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_bzip2-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-s-1_51.lib
libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
```

How come the iostreams libs were not produced on the original compilation? Very odd.